# Complete Metrics

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question: for $x, y \in \Bbb R$ let $d_1(x,y) = max |x_j-y_j|$ for $j=1,2,...,k$
Show that $d_1$ is a complete metric for $\Bbb R^k$.

I have already shown that it is a metric, and now I am confused about the 
"complete" notion. My textbook's definition of a complete metric is that every cauchy sequence in my space, in this case $\Bbb R^k$ defined with this metric, converges to an element within the space. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have everything you need. For a lot of topology/real analysis problems, I find that just writing down the definitions of all the words I'm working with goes a long way. A Cauchy sequence is defined that, for all $\epsilon$, there is some $k$ so that $d_1(a_k,a_{k+m}) < \epsilon$. It converges to a point in the space if there some point $p_0 = (x,y)$ such that there is a similar $k$ for all $\epsilon$ that bounds $d_1(p_0,a_k) < \epsilon$. What would this point have as coordinates? Take the sequence of $x$ coordinates and $y$ coordinates separately, show they converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^k$ with respect to the metric $d_1$. By definition, this means that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every pair integers $m,n\geq N$, one has that $$d_1(x^{(m)},x^{(n)})=\max_{j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}}\left|\,x_j^{(m)}-x_j^{(n)}\right|<\varepsilon.$$ This implies that $$\left|\,x_j^{(m)}-x_j^{(n)}\right|<\varepsilon\quad\text{for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$}$$ whenever $m,n\geq N$. Hence, $(x_j^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ with respect to the ordinary Euclidean metric (difference of absolute values) for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

Now, the space of real numbers is complete with respect to the ordinary Euclidean metric. This implies that for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, there exists some $x_j\in\mathbb R$ such that the sequence $(x_j^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x_j$ with respect to the Euclidean metric. As a consequence, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exist some $N_j\in\mathbb N$ such that for any integer $n\geq N_j$, one has $$\left|\,x_j^{(n)}-x_j\right|<\varepsilon.$$

I claim that the sequence $(x^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^k$ converges to $x\equiv(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ with respect to the metric $d_1$, which will complete the proof. Let $N\equiv\max\{N_1,\ldots,N_k\}\in\mathbb N$. If $n$ is an integer such that $n\geq N$, then $n\geq N_j$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ by the definition of $N$. By the preceding argument, this yields that $$\left|\,x_j^{(n)}-x_j\right|<\varepsilon$$ for every $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, whence $$d_1(x^{(n)},x)=\max_{j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}}\left|\,x_j^{(n)}-x_j\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Hello, sorry for asking such a question so late. I am reading this post. Can you give an explicit example of metric corresponding to this condition?

Comment: @Mike The metric here is concretely given, so I am unsure what you mean by “explicit example.” You can read more about this metric’s properties and interpretations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance).

Comment: I am seeking a complete metric that satisfies $X=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_j^n=x_j$, $j=1,...,k$,  and I think the metric in this post solves my problem. Is this metric with the space separable and is there a countable basis for open set? Thank you.

Comment: @Mike I would suggest focusing on the standard Euclidean metric (which is in a certain sense equivalent to the metric in the above problem). Under that metric topology, $\mathbb R^k$ is separable for any positive integer $k$ ($\mathbb Q^k$ is a countable dense subset). Moreover, the open balls with rational centers and rational radii form a countable basis for the metric topology. The resulting metric space is also complete. All these facts are pretty basic topological properties of Euclidean spaces, covered in a plethora of decent real-analysis textbooks or freely available online resources.

Comment: In this case, can I pick $x_j^n$ and $x_j$ as rational sequences under the Euclidean metric $d(x^n,x)=|x_j^n-x_j|$, which they both belong to equivalence class of Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}^k$, or are there other ways to pick sequences?

Comment: @Mike I’m not sure I understand what you are trying to prove here.